# What happens if a NON-EU national traveling to Budapest by BUS from Berlin with a new Hungarian student D visa which was issued in berlin

Tags: schengen, study, hungary

I am from India, arrived in Germany with long term student visa and living, studying in Germany from the past 11  months, I changed my university and moving to Budapest, Hungary with New Student D visa by BUS from berlin TO Budapest. I got a single entry visa and valid for 6 months and have to apply for a residence permit within 30 days of my arrival in Hungary.

My question is, can I travel by bus from Berlin to Budapest?, will there be any problem with immigration near border check since i am going with new visa , which was issued by the Hungarian consulate in BERLIN.

Kindly let me know.

Comment: This is outside topic of this site. You should be able to go with bus. If you need some stamps (and this part is off topic in my opinion), you should either get it at police station at boundary or in Budapest in some specific place. If you have a visa, why do you think there could be problems?